# How do I extract text from a html tag without extracting other values in the tag?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I extract some part of the code/text inside a tag

Here is the markup :

```
<li class="price-current">

            <span class="price-current-label">
            </span>₹ 25,462;
            <a href="https://www.newegg.com/global/in-en/msi-geforce-rtx-2060-rtx-2060-ventus-6g-oc/p/N82E16814137380?buyingoptions=New&amp;Description=Video%20Cards" class="price-current-num" onclick="Javascript:s_search_results_clickthrough(this);">(3 Offers)</a>
            <span class="price-current-range">
                <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
            </span>

    </li>
```

I want to extract only the '₹ 25,462' part

The code I used:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser") 
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

price_container = contain.find("div", {"class": "item-info"}).find("div", {"class": "item-action"}).ul.find('li',{"class":"price-current"}).text
```

My Result:

```
₹ 25,462 (3 Offers)

–
```

I need to remove the '(3 offers)' and '-' parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` module for extracting the price:

```
data = '''<li class="price-current">

            <span class="price-current-label">
            </span>₹ 25,462;
            <a href="https://www.newegg.com/global/in-en/msi-geforce-rtx-2060-rtx-2060-ventus-6g-oc/p/N82E16814137380?buyingoptions=New&amp;Description=Video%20Cards" class="price-current-num" onclick="Javascript:s_search_results_clickthrough(this);">(3 Offers)</a>
            <span class="price-current-range">
                <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
            </span>

    </li>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
price = re.findall(r'₹\s+[\d,]+', soup.select_one('li.price-current').text)[0]
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
₹ 25,462
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use bs4 and next_sibling

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<li class="price-current">

            <span class="price-current-label">
            </span>₹ 25,462;
            <a href="https://www.newegg.com/global/in-en/msi-geforce-rtx-2060-rtx-2060-ventus-6g-oc/p/N82E16814137380?buyingoptions=New&amp;Description=Video%20Cards" class="price-current-num" onclick="Javascript:s_search_results_clickthrough(this);">(3 Offers)</a>
            <span class="price-current-range">
                <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
            </span>

    </li>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml') 
print(soup.select_one('.price-current-label').next_sibling.strip())
```